# What's the correct way of adding a .mov file to a webpage?

Tags: video, mov

I've been having a look around and I can't understand why this is not working ;)

my code (testfile)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <title></title>
  </head>
      <body>
        <video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" name="Video-Name" src="video/cloisterarch.mov"></video>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I open this file on chrome, the video is there, and I can hear audio, but it's just a white screen with the play/pause and volume buttons, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .mov file is a movie in Quicktime format. The video and the audio can be encoded using different codecs. Depending on the codec used and depending on the browser and operation system, the video or the audio might not play.

The Quicktime format isn't widely supported. So you are better off converting to a different format such as .mp4 (MPEG-4).

The best solution however is to convert the video to several different formats and resolutions and let the browser pick the most suitable one.

Comment: Ahh alright, thank you for the fast answer, helped a lot, Did actually work after doing what you said, (Sorry for the silly question, still learning!)